# Can I backup my arch build externally?

Tags: arch-linux

I've recently installed arch Linux and I am loving it. However I really want to somehow install the exact same build on a different computer. AND/OR create a backup of my build. Preferably the backup would be to an external drive. Is there already a common method for doing what I'm asking about?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of common methods for doing that. Details depend on how exactly your installation looks like, which you told us nothing about.

Assuming for exampler you installation uses a single partition `/dev/sda1`, one of the simpler methods is to create a single partition of exactly the same size both on your backup drive and the drive that's going to end up on the different computer (connect it temporarily to the current computer), and the just copy the complete partition. You'll see many people using `dd` for that, but `cp` works as well.

Restrictions for this methods are that the destination partition needs to be exactly the same size, and that you should have installed all necessary drivers for the second computer already on your current installation (which often will be the case).

There are other, more flexible but more involved methods, like `rsync`.

Comment: so what im getting from this, is i am copying my sda1 partition and not just the space that is used on it? I'll also read more into rsync.

So even if my sda1 partition is 465gigs and the external drive is 1TB i could not simply use dd or cp?

Comment: Yes, you are copying the complete partition. If the partition is mostly empty this will take longer than copying all the files, of course - you trade simplicity for speed. Yes, you can also use `cp -a ...` to just copy all files (but you have to be careful, your filesystem will contain device nodes, mount points etc., so that's not straightforward.